# gnu make: why called "top-level" target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the context of the GNU make tool the term "top-level target" is used.
Are there other types of targets? Can there be targets "nested" inside other targets?

I could not find anything searching for "nested target", "inner target" or "enclosing target".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "nested", "inner", or "enclosing" target in a makefile.  Of course, you can "collect" targets implicitly by declaring prerequisites: if you build the target it also builds all its prerequisites.

The term *top-level target* as used in that section of the GNU make manual is your subjective understanding of the final goals that your makefile wants to create.  So if your makefile should create a program and a library, those are the "top-level targets" that section refers to.

That page is discussing only a set of common targets that many makefiles implement.  None of those are built into make or have any special meaning to make itself.

Comment: Ok, so the term "top-level target" has only a "logical" meaning, and targets are qualified with this term depending on the project (what targets are meant to be the "result" of running the makefile for the particular project). Did I understand that correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The top-level target is the target given to `make` on the command line. Or it's the default target in the `Makefile`. Other targets would be intermediate or dependent targets.

Comment: I don't think that is right. For example, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html), it says that "[...] all - Make all the top-level targets the makefile knows about.[...]". Therefore top-level targets are not determined by the targets that are given to `make` to build, they are determined by the fact that they are defined at the top-level in the makefile (I believe).

Comment: The targets named in the reference -- all, clean, install etc. -- are just suggestions for named targets that [all makefiles should honour](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets).  They are not treated as special in any sense.

Comment: There are special because they are [.PHONY targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: Sure, but they are only `.PHONY` if the author of the makefile *makes* them `.PHONY`.  My point was simply that `make` itself has no implicit notion of those targets -- right?